# cleaning text files in python 2 : TypeError: coercing to Unicode:

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, text-mining

I am trying to clean up so text files in python. I want to take out stop words, digits and the new line character. But I keep getting **coercing to Unicode python text** . Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from string import digits

 def cleanupDoc(s):
     s = s.translate(None,digits)
     s = s.rstrip('\n')  
     stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
     tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
     cleanup = " ".join(filter(lambda word: word not in stopset, s.split()))
     return cleanup

flist=glob.glob('/home/uiucinfo/Desktop/*txt')
mylist=[]
for fname in flist:
    tfile = open(fname, 'r+')
    line = tfile.readlines()
    #line = cleanupDoc(line)
    mylist.append(line)

for fdoc in mylist:
    doc = open(fdoc)
    newDoc = cleanupDoc(doc)
    doc.close()
```

My Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: pretty obvious error, you are passing a list instead of a string. Have you tried adding print statements to debug?

Comment: How am I passing a list? I thought that I am accessing the documents in the second for loop.

Comment: you are appending readlines which is a list to mylist, I would recommend using with to open your files or at the very least closing them, might pay to check out a pep-8 style guide too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
form nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
#nltk.download() 
import string
from string import digits
import glob
import re


def cleanupDoc(s):    
     #s = s.translate(None,digits)
     #s = s.rstrip('\n')  
     stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
     tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
     cleanup = " ".join(filter(lambda word: word not in stopset, s.split()))
     return cleanup

flist=glob.glob('/home/uiucinfo/Desktop/*txt')
mylist=[]
for fname in flist:
    tfile = open(fname, 'r+')
    line = tfile.readlines()
    #line = cleanupDoc(line)
    mylist.append(line)

for fdoc in mylist:
    # remove \n or digit from fdoc
    fdoc = [re.sub(r'[\"\n]|\d', '', x) for x in fdoc]
    # convert list to string 
    fdoc = ''.join(fdoc)
    print fdoc
    newDoc = cleanupDoc(fdoc)
    print " newDoc: " , newDoc
```

Comment: It would be better if you described how you fixed the issue and what you changed, rather just posting the code.

Answer (score 1):

`tfile.readlines()` gives you a list of lines, which you are appending to another list:

```
for fname in flist:
    tfile = open(fname, 'r+')
    line = tfile.readlines()
    mylist.append(line)
```

In result, you have a list of lists in `mylist`.
The following should fix the problem:

```
for fname in flist:
    tfile = open(fname, 'r+')
    line = tfile.readlines()
    mylist += line
```

This will give you a list of strings in `mylist`.